# Не видит пространство имен, Net 4.5, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespace

Всем привет! Есть такой вопросик... Взял исходник отсюда https://github.com/Eryux/miband-heartrate. Открыл в Visual Studio 2017 с установленным SDK. Пишет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В свойствах проекта использую NET4.5. Когда создаю чистый проект на С# все пространства имен видятся. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Чистый проект использует версию выше чем 4.5. В этом скорей всего и проблема

Comment: Соглашусь с @Zergatul, в свойствах проекта стоит указать версию .net повыше...